# How to set less to clear the screen on exit only if the output fills more than a single page?

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, command-line-tool

I'm trying to figure out a way to pipe the output of a command (`ag`, in this case) to `less -F` (i.e. `--quit-if-one-screen`), but if the output is less than one page, the screen just flashes the content before it disappears. I've read that I can use `-X` (`--no-init`) to disable clearing the screen upon exiting `less`, but in that case long output doesn't get cleared either, which kinda defeats the purpose of a pager.

Is there a way to make `less -X` work with `-F`? I.e., to clear the output upon exiting less, except if the output fits in a single page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very question has been [answered in Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107315/less-quit-if-one-screen-without-no-init). The top-voted answer there has actually been expanded into a full-fledged command-line tool that can act as a replacement for `less`: https://github.com/stefanheule/smartless.

I've been using it myself with great results (plus the author is very responsive to bug reports and feature requests on Github), so I highly recommend it to anyone facing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2018 now and Less is available in version 530. One of the key changes is the behavior of `less -F` with content of less than one full screen.

The solution is easy: Install Less 530 from your package repository, or [download from Free Software Foundation](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/) and compile it yourself. Then you can have `less -F` leaving the content on screen if it doesn't fill up one full screen.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like [several popular distros (e.g. Debian and Ubuntu) still don't have version 530 in their package repositories](https://repology.org/metapackage/less/versions), but hopefully those numbers will quickly dwindle towards zero.

Comment: @waldyrious Hi. It isn't quite hard to compile Less by yourself. You only need `libncurses5-dev` as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that :)